# How to distinguish if a PHP property is undefined or set to NULL

Tags: php, oop, variables, null, variable-types

So I am facing this problem. I have a class representing a record in my database (User in this example). The class has as many properties as the database table has columns. For simplicity, I have just three in my example:

1. `$id` - ID of the user (must be set to a positive integer for registered user, might be set to 0 for user objects that aren't saved in the database yet)
2. `$name` - Name of user (must be set for every user, but before loading it from the database might be undefined)
3. `$email` - E-mail address of the user (might be NULL in case the user didn't submit an e-mail address)

My (simplified) class looks like this:

```
<?php
class User
{
  private $id;
  private $name;
  private $email;
  
  public function __construct(int $id = 0)
  {
      if (!empty($id)){ $this->id = $id; }
      //If $id === 0, it means that the record represented by this instance isn't saved in the database yet and the property will be filled after calling the save() method
  }
  
  public function initialize(string $name = '', $email = '')
  {
      //If any of the parameters isn't specified, prevent overwriting curent values
      if ($name === ''){ $name = $this->name; }
      if ($email === ''){ $email = $this->email; }
      
      $this->name = $name;
      $this->email = $email;
  }
  
  public function load()
  {
      if (!empty($this->id))
      {
          //Load name and e-mail from the database and save them into properties
      }
  }

  public function save()
  {
      if (!empty($this->id))
      {
          //Update existing user record in the database 
      }
      else
      {
          //Insert a new record into the table and set $this->id to the ID of the last inserted row
      }
  }
  
  public function isFullyLoaded()
  {
      $properties = get_object_vars($this);
      foreach ($properties as $property)
      {
          if (!isset($property)){ return false; }   //TODO - REPLACE isset() WITH SOMETHING ELSE
      }
      return true;
  }
  
  //Getters like getName() and getId() would come here
}
```

Now finally to my problem. As you can see, the instance of this class can be created without all properties set. That's a problem in case I want to e. g. call `getName()` while the name isn't known yet (it wasn't set via the `initialize()` method and load() wasn't called). For that, I wrote method `isFullyLoaded()` which checks if all properties are known and if not, `load()` should be called (from the method calling `isFullyLoaded()`. And the core of the problem is, that some variables might be empty strings (''), zero values (0) or even null (like the `$email` property). So I want to distinguish variables that have any value set (including null) and those who have never been assigned any value.

Specific example: I want to achieve this code:

```
$user1 = new User(1);
$user1->initialize('Vic', 'nerd.from.klamath@fallout2.com');
var_dump($user1->isFullyLoaded());

$user2 = new User(2);
$user2->initialize('Cassidy', null); //No e-mail was specified during the registration
var_dump($user2->isFullyLoaded());

$user3 = new User(3);
$user3->initialize('Myron'); //E-mail isn't known yet, but might be saved in the database
var_dump($user3->isFullyLoaded());
```

to output this:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

TL:DR How do distinguish undefined variable and variable which has been assigned NULL in PHP?

Comment: Well, by having defined the properties in the class, like `private $name;` ... it HAS been set a value. A value of null. So you are wanting to know if a property has been overwritten from the default definition?

Comment: If an email was not specified during registration, wouldn't doing `$user2->initialize('Cassidy', '');` instead, work out better? You are clearing the `null` with an `empty`, and thus `isset` will work as intended. You would also need to change the `initialize` defaults to: `public function initialize(string $name = null, $email = null)` and then check on `if ($name === null){ $name = $this->name; }` etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would work in this case and for all string properties, but them what about other variable types. Let's say that I would have a property called `$postCount` or something like that, which could have 0 as a perfectly valid value, not an unknown one.

Comment: The thing you probably need to reconcile with PHP is... `null` = unset (or undefined as you put it). If you work towards always keeping this as `null`... and any other value is considered as having been defined... then it will work out. A `0` will not cause `isset($val)` to result as false. It WILL if you change that to `if !empty($val)` for example.

Comment: Basically this "*How do distinguish undefined variable and variable which has been assigned NULL in PHP?*" will cause you so much grief with PHP. Because an `undefined` variable in php is one that hasn't even been created, at all. Like doing `echo $thiswasnevermade;` will result in an undefined variable error. But `$thiswasmade = null; echo $thiswasmade;` will not error... as its been defined.

Comment: Yeah. But the property/variable I don't want to see as valid is declared, just isn't ever assigned any value (defined). So declared and undefined.

Comment: Right. Its a sticky situation to figure out if it has been changed from original `null` to a new `null` :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has not the value undefined like javascript. But it is not strict typed so if you do not find a better solution here is one with an custom type UNDEFINED

```
<?php
class UNDEFINED { }

class Test {
var $a;

    function __construct( $a='' ) {
            $this->a = new UNDEFINED();
            if( $a !== '' ) {
                    $this->a = $a;
            }
    }


    function isDefined() {
            $result =true;
            if(gettype($this->a) === 'object'){
             if(get_class($this->a) === 'UNDEFINED') {
               $result=false;
             }
            }

            echo gettype($this->a) . get_class($this->a);
            return $result;
    }

}

$test= new Test();

$test->isDefined();
```

Here is a may be litte better version which used instanceof instead of get_call and getType

```
<?php
class UNDEFINED { }

class Test {
  var $id;
  var $a;
  var $b;

  function __construct( $id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->a = new UNDEFINED();
    $this->b = new UNDEFINED();
  }

  function init( $a = '' , $b = '') {
    $this->a = $this->setValue($a,$this->a);
    $this->b = $this->setValue($b,$this->b);
  }

  function setValue($a,$default) {
    return $a === '' ? $default : $a;
  }

  function isUndefined($a) {
    return $a instanceof UNDEFINED;
  }
 
  public function isFullyLoaded()
  {
    $result = true;
    $properties = get_object_vars($this);
    print_r($properties);
    foreach ($properties as $property){
      $result = $result && !$this->isUndefined($property);
      if ( !$result) break;
    }
    return $result;
  }

  function printStatus() {
    if($this->isFullyLoaded() ) {
      echo 'Loaded!';
    } else {
      echo 'Not loaded';
    }
  }
}

$test= new Test(1); 
$test->printStatus();
$test->init('hello');
$test->printStatus();
$test->init('', null);
$test->printStatus();
```

Comment: That is quite an elegant solution. Thanks a lot. I was thinking about adding a new property, that would store names of unloaded properties (undefined), but this is much better. Maybe I would just add __toString() method to the UNDEFINED class, that would return 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to introduce the custom *Undefined* class (as singleton). Additionally, be sure that your class properties are typed:

```
class Undefined
{
    private static Undefined $instance;

    protected function __constructor()
    {
    }

    protected function __clone()
    {
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        throw new Exception("Not allowed for a singleton.");
    }

    static function getInstance(): Undefined
    {
        return self::$instance ?? (self::$instance = new static());
    }
}

class Person
{
    private int $age;

    public function getAge(): int|Undefined
    {
        return $this->age ?? Undefined::getInstance();
    }
}

$person = new Person();

if ($person->getAge() instanceof Undefined) {
    // do something
}
```

But there is a downside with using singleton pattern, because all the *undefined* objects in your app will be strictly equal to each other. Otherwise, every get operation returning *undefined* value will have a side effect namely another piece of allocated RAM.

Answer (score -1):

Use `property_exists()`:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// oop:

class A {
    public $null_var = null;
}

$a = new A;

if(property_exists($a, 'null_var')) {
    echo "null_var property exists\n";
}

if(property_exists($a, 'unset_var')) {
    echo "unset_var property exists\n";
}

// procedural:

$null_var = null;

if(array_key_exists('null_var', $GLOBALS)) {
    echo "null_var variable exists\n";
}

if(array_key_exists('unset_var', $GLOBALS)) {
    echo "unset_var variable exists\n";
}

// output:
// null_var property exists
// null_var variable exists
```

Comment: This isn't going to work, as all properties exist as mentioned by the OP.

Comment: The problem is, that if I have another property which isn't assigned anything by default, it will return that the property exists, but I want to know that it has never been assigned any value.

Comment: Oops I missed get_object_vars() in OP. Maybe use a magic number which means unset?